# Why the body don't fall down in Loop-the-Loop Situation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

In Ramamurti Shankar playlist fundamentals of physics

he talked about Loop-the-Loop example which is if a trolley in a roller coaster and it's at the top of it why the roller coaster didn't fall down

his explanation was that when the trolley at the top it has an horizontal component of velocity and the acceleration that pushing it downward give it a vertical component of velocity and the combination of the vertical and horizontal component make it move tangentially and he provided this image [image]

My question is as follows: if there is a vertical component is added to it's velocity how it can move with the same speed all the path? and also how it's direction didn't shift toward the center with an angle

Answer (score 0):

The car doesn't move with the same speed around the loop, it's slowest at the top.

I would explain this by saying the radius of curvature of the ballistic trajectory (read: inertial free fall) is larger than the radius of the loop.

Comment: if we are taking about uniform circular motion, the body moves wi the same speed all the path and don't shift toward the center why this happen and there's a vertical component added to it's velocity?

Comment: "roller coaster" implies gravity. Loop-de-loop implies it's vertical. It is not uniform circular motion.  Perhaps you mean "motorcycle" and "wall-of-death"?

Comment: ,,but if we consider a uniform circular motion and at the highest point, the force is downward so why the body don't Gain another component of velocity in the y direction and change the total magnitude of velocity moving with ? , Prof Shankar did say that he's gained a vertical component and this vertical component will be added to it's horizontal component which must make the object move with different magnitude of velocity why this doesn't happen?

Comment: @Mans Just use conservation of energy to get speed. Forces perpendicular to velocity don't change its magnitude.

Comment: Well I am not talking about the velocity in the horizontal component,iam taking why can't the vertical Force itself create an vertical velocity component independent on the horizontal component,it's like if there is a car moving and you pull it upward it has an horizontal component which is didn't change but it also has an vertical component came from the application of the vertical Force and the direction of it's motion will be like $tan(\theta)=v_{y}÷v_{x}$